# How to get the list of installed packages on Ubuntu/Debian w/o command or w/o looking at pkg.log?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dpkg, debian

I have to extract the list of installed packages on Ubuntu/Debian without using command or without looking at dpkg.log?

The basic requirement is to get the list of installed packages on Debian/Ubuntu OS from the packages db file(if any)
I'm able to get the list of available packages from following file,

```
/var/lib/dpkg/available
```

But this file contains all the packages including not installed.

Is there any other db file on Debian/Ubuntu which contains the list of only installed packages?

Answer (score 1):

The file that contains the same information as that provided by the `dpkg -l` command is `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. From the `FILES` section of `man dpkg`:

> ```
>    /var/lib/dpkg/status
>           Statuses of available  packages.  This  file  contains  information
>           about  whether  a package is marked for removing or not, whether it
>           is installed or not, etc. See section  INFORMATION  ABOUT  PACKAGES
>           for more info.
>
>           The  status  file  is  backed  up  daily in /var/backups. It can be
>           useful if it's lost or corrupted due to filesystems troubles.
>
>    The format and contents of a binary package are described in deb(5).
> ```

But your "w/o command" requirement makes little sense since you will need to write a command to parse it. For example

```
awk -vRS= '/Status: install/ {print $2}' /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

will be roughly equivalent to `dpkg -l | awk '$1 == "ii" {print $2}'` (they will differ in sort order and some possible architecture suffixes like `:amd64`).